# Why was this move in a puzzle?

Tags: puzzles, beginner

I was on the chess.com app this morning doing the daily puzzle and it wanted me to play Re2. This is questionable to me, because it just delays the mate, but I figured I might have missed something. Then what really perplexed me is that Black then plays Qg7. It appears to me that Black is sacrificing his queen for no reason when he has a mate in 2. I don't see how White has time to mount an attack on Black or come back to defend in time. What am I missing?

```
[FEN "5r1k/1pQ4p/3nB1p1/3P4/5p2/1P5P/rq5P/4R1RK w - - 0 1"]

1. Re2 Qg7 2. Qxg7+ Kxg7 3. Rxa2
```

Comment: Hint: long diagonal

Comment: You can also try the analysis board (the icon with the magnifying glass) to see what could happen with alternative moves. Above the analysis board, it shows what the computer thinks is the best move (may keep changing as it calculates deeper).

Comment: This is a tactical motif known as diversion, and might be considered a bit more advanced than pins and forks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If black plays QxR then white plays Qc3+ with mate to follow. Black's Qg7 stops the mate. With the black queen on b2 white cannot play Qc3. The Re2 move is to divert the black queen

```
[FEN "5r1k/1pQ4p/3nB1p1/3P4/5p2/1P5P/rq5P/4R1RK w - - 0 1"]

1. Re2 Qxe2 2. Qc3+ Qe5 3. Qxe5+ Rf6 4. Qxf6#
```

Comment: Damn, the worst part is I always get tricked by these kind of moves too!